# How to split a pdf doc vertically and display the pages in order

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a pdf doc which has 2 pages per page I want to split the page vertically and display the page in order (eg 100 page pfd doc will get converted to 200 pages doc)

I want to code it in may be php/javascript (is it possible). I want to upload any pdf doc to my website and then split it vertically then display the pages in order

Please let me how how to do this, I have tried to google but I could not find a solution

thanks

Edit:

I am trying to use clipRectangel() method:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php'; 
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('pages.pdf');
$page = $pdf->pages[0]; 
$page->clipRectangle(10, 10, 30, 30); 
$pdf->save('new.pdf'); 
?>
```

I am trying to use clipRectangle to split vertically but I am not getting any modified pdf in 'new.pdf' I also want to order the pages,please suggest any better way to use zend. It would be helpful if you can give me few lines of code.

Comment: Do you want to produce output as a new, 200 page PDF file, or some other format (eg HTML)?

Comment: ya please let me know the both options .... output as pdf or as html.. thanks

Comment: I take it you can't go back to source and get the PDF produced in a different format? If you can add any detail about how the double-page PDF doc is produced, maybe that will help someone offer thoughts on that; as Christian says, PDFs aren't all that editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty tall order.

Your best bet is to use Zend_Pdf which allows [loading and altering of (unprotected) PDF files](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.create.html) in php. Javascript cannot do this.

This is of course not something that will work with just any PDF in any circumstance. You can get cut off text (half on one page, half on the other) as the entire process is not like HTML text.

Converting a PDF to HTML is a whole other thing.

**Update:** I've taken your code simply for illustration. Haven't tested this, but if you get errors, you should be able to find the solution rather quickly.

```
require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php'; 

$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('pages.pdf');
$pdfnew = new Zend_Pdf();


foreach ($pdf->pages as $page) {
    $curpage = $page;

    // Clipping for first part, enter your own numbers..
    $curpage->clipRectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
    $pdfnew->pages[] = $curpage;

    $curpage = $page;

    // Clipping for second part, enter your own numbers..
    $curpage->clipRectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
    $pdfnew->pages[] = $curpage;
}

$pdfnew->save('new.pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks ... it would be great if you could give some lines of code, using zend pdf to split a pdf vertically into 2 half

Comment: Sorry for that I have accepted it again ..I didnt kw how to reopen this question